# Why does my hylang program fail at parsing?

Tags: lisp, hy

I have written a small hylang program that parses a log. However, when i try to evaluate it, i get the following error:

> File "", line 8, column 38
>
> ```
>         (setv rule (.next irule)))))))
>                                    ^ LexException: Ran into a RPAREN where it wasn't expected.
> ```

The function in question (also gives an error when evaluated separately) is the following:

```
(defmain [&rest args]
  (setv inname (get args 1))
  (setv outname (get args 2))
  (with [ifile (open inname 'r')]
    (with [ofile (open outname 'w')]
      (setv tl (Tableline))
      (setv irule (iter (.get-rule tl)))
      (setv rule (.next irule))
      (for [line ifile]
        (setv match (re.match (get rule 0) line))
        (when match
          (for [(, group-num attr-data) (enumerate (get rule 1))]
            (setattr tl (get attr-data 1) (apply (get attr-data 0)
                                                 [(.group match (inc group-num))])))
          (if (. tl ready) (write ofile (str tl)))
          (setv rule (.next irule)))))))
```

As far as i can tell, it is balanced expression, with all parens in their places. Why does the lexer fails?

The full text of my program is here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9T7r8WhH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for making strings.

In lisps, the single quote is used for something completely different than making strings- "quoting" the next form. When lisp code is parsed, expressions like `'a` are transformed into `(quote a)`. Similarly, `'(hello)` becomes `(quote (hello))`. Note that there is only one ' mark, as it always wraps the next expression. The quote form lets you "turn off" evaluation for a single expression. Look up lisp quotation- it's pretty useful, and is important for some of the more powerful features of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Should have used "w" and "r" instead of 'w' and 'r'